# How to make git log output that just shows date and hash on one line?

Tags: git, git-log

I need to get the Date and commit results of a set of github  in this format:

```
Date Commit
19 Mar 2015 b6959eafe0df6031485509c539e22eaf2780919c
1 Apr 2015 9a1f13339cc7d43930440c2350ea3060b72c8503
1 Apr 2015 1e76036421ca4d72c371182fc494af514911b099
```

I am able to get the date with this command:

```
git log | grep Date: | awk '{print  $4 " " $3 " " $6}'
```

and the commit with

```
git log | grep commit | awk '{print $2}'
```

How can I combine the commands, so as to print both results in the same line?

Here is an example of the git log:

```
commit 1e76036421ca4d72c371182fc494af514911b099
Author: xxxx
Date:   Wed Apr 1 17:35:36 2015 +0200

    First web app commit

    First web app commit

commit 9a1f13339cc7d43930440c2350ea3060b72c8503
Author: xxxx
Date:   Wed Apr 1 17:28:42 2015 +0200

   change from app to website

commit b6959eafe0df6031485509c539e22eaf2780919c
Author: xxx
Date:   Thu Mar 19 18:58:33 2015 +0100

   First remote commit: hello world

    scheleton of the project now available

commit a41d419de46a59e72dbc52e5f39c9d8a8a9af72a
Author: xxxx
Date:   Thu Mar 19 17:31:16 2015 +0100

    Initial commit
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "git log" command is powerful enough to handle this on its own.   Play around with variations on this:

```
git log --date=iso --pretty=format:"date={%ad}, commit={%H}"
```

For me this outputs:

```
date={2014-12-12 14:14:23 -0800}, commit={75390af8bcd42c4dde6d841dc53f66a9ca91f460}
date={2014-12-09 18:53:32 -0800}, commit={8dcf9eb10611e6ac778e518cf37efb041c69f5b5}
date={2014-12-11 17:17:26 -0800}, commit={c3c1120b6dda6b317e1de5c7fe4eed7c8741ea1a}
```

To achieve the exact format you specified (though with the date formatted a bit more reasonably), try this:

```
 ​git log --date=short --pretty=format:"%ad %H"
```

Which outputs things like:

```
2015-08-18 1d0ca5a596f02958c4ba8ff269def3f235c64495
2015-08-18 d92fc3ebb62d2ca3e24322db2b669fdaebde7ea1
2015-08-18 6ba3970620e19699c2969b1eed5c479b07b8908a
```

Comment: Thank you! The last suggestion work perfectly.
​git log --date=short --pretty=format:"%ad %H"

Answer (score 1):

You more-or-less *never* need `grep | awk` as `awk` can do the matching for you.

So `grep Date: | awk '{print  $4 " " $3 " " $6}'` can be rewritten as `awk '/Date:/ {print  $4 " " $3 " " $6}'` and `grep commit | awk '{print $2}'` can be rewritten as `awk '/commit/ {print $2}'`.

That should be enough to give you the first inklings of how to solve your problem.

Combine the awk scripts.

```
git log | awk '
    # Print the header line (remove if you do not want it).
    BEGIN {print "Date Commit"}
    /^commit/ {
        # Save the current commit
        commit=$2
        # Skip to the next line
        next
    }
    /^Date:/ {
        # Print the fields from the current line and the saved commit
        print $4, $3, $6, commit
        # Clear the saved commit Just in Case
        commit=""
    }
'
```

That being said you can get *almost* the format you want from `git log` itself:

```
$ git log --format='%ad %H' --date=short
2015-03-19 b6959eafe0df6031485509c539e22eaf2780919c
2015-04-1 9a1f13339cc7d43930440c2350ea3060b72c8503
2015-04-1 1e76036421ca4d72c371182fc494af514911b099
```

Which you could convert to your desired output with some awk if you wanted. (Transposing the date fields is trivial, converting to the month names would require some more code/work.)

Comment: Thank you!  
Now I have another small problem I cannot solve...  
  
I need to launch two commands for each line:  
  
git checkout ######  
sonar-sunner -Dsonar.projectDate=date 

for example, in your git log, the first line should be:  
git checkout  b6959eafe0df6031485509c539e22eaf2780919c  
sonar-runner -Dsonar.projectDate=2015-03-19

Comment: If you need output like that then use the second bit here and make the format string look like what you want. It can contain any non-format text you want. So `git checkout %H; sonar-sunner -Dsonar.projectDate=%ad` or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You may be find your solution with pretty format ?

http://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
git log | awk '/^commit / { commit = $2 }
               /^Date: /  { printf "%s %s %s %s\n", $4, $3, $6, commit }'
```

Capture the commit information in the variable commit.  When a date comes along, print the date and commit information.

It is often a bad idea to pipe the output of `grep` to `awk`; `awk` is perfectly capable of doing the filtering that `grep` does.

Answer (score 0):

This would do

```
git log -5 --pretty=format:"%ad %H" | awk '{print $3, $2, $5, $7}'

10 Aug 2015 9fb4b1b5e7bcbc7f55e40ceae1758a7288673a51
10 Aug 2015 3d613862ca53787c97a42e8e2c37e09c8752b637
7 Aug 2015 727af2863dbe9f7b4da9189bc12f97a99aac5705
7 Aug 2015 1438b43b5755079bb3e62c819bfef2629d8336e9
7 Aug 2015 34303c19fb11482d66fc3c1102bc8d8b433af21a
```